# CAReplicatorLayer random position

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-animation, careplicatorlayer

How do you introduce randomness within a CAReplicatorLayer layer? For example, randomizing the positions of each particle.

Best,
Vance

Answer (score 0):

You must `setInstanceTransform:(CATransform3D)transform` to each replicated layer.

Use that in conjunction with `arc4rand()` to randomise the positions..